# Calling functions on lists

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have a spectra of wavelengths as a list and some number of other lists I use in a formula (using tmm.tmm_core).  Is there something more efficient than iterating through the wavelength if I'm just basically doing the same thing for all wavelengths?
Example

```
def go(n, thk, theta):
     #do stuff
     return(something)

wv = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a_vec = [3, 7, 3, 9]
b_vec = [6, 5, 9, 3]
c_vec = [0, 1, 8, 9]
theta = 0
th = [10, 1, 10]
final = []

for i in range(len(wv)):
    n = [a[i], b[i], c[i]]
    answer = go(n, th, theta)
    final.append(answer)
```

in reality there are maybe 5000-10000 rows.  It just seems to lag a bit when I press go and I assume it's because of the iteration.  Pretty new to optimizing so I haven't used any benchmarking tools or anything.

Comment: Iterating through a `range` doesn't cost much at all. Maybe the list comprehension would be faster than appending to the list continually, but probably most of the reason it's slow is because of what `go` is doing. Try [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html) your code to see what's really going on.

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of your lists within a custom list like `C_list` and use `map` to create a new list `all_len` contain the length of all lists then use a list comprehension to create the list `final` :

```
all_len=map(len,C_list)
final =[[go([a[i], b[i], c[i]], th, theta) for i in range(li)] for li in all_len]
```

Also if the length of `a` and `b` and `c` are equal you can use `zip` function to zip then and refuse of multiple indexing :

```
all_len=map(len,C_list)
z=zip(a,b,c)
final =[[go(z[i], th, theta) for i in range(li)] for li in all_len]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `map` function in Python!

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = [5,6,7,8]
>>> map(lambda x,y: x+y, list1, list2)
[6, 8, 10, 12]
```

it takes in a function (in the above case, an anonymous lambda function), one or more lists and returns another list. At each iteration within the function, both lists are iterated and the result is added to the new list. You don't need to limit yourself to the expressive power of a lambda statement; you can also use globally defined functions as in the case below:

```
>>> def go(a,b,c):
...     return a+b+c
... 
>>> map(go, list1,list2, range(9,13))
[15, 18, 21, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to perform an operation on every item in the list, then you're gonna have to go through every item in the list. However, you could gain speed through the use of list comprehensions: [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)